# Need to determine when linux/OSX is fully initialized

Tags: linux, shell, osx-lion

I need a shell scripting way to determine when a remote linux/OSX has completed all /etc/init.d/* for what ever run levels I have chosen to run in.

since I know I can ssh into a virutal box on my net while it is still booting and run commands like /bin/true or /bin/ps that not everthing is in the state it needs to be.

essentially I need to

```
while [ ${INIT_STILL_RUNNING_ON_REMOTE_SYSTEN}  ]
do
   sleep 30
done
ssh remoteUser@remoteSystem:command
```

Comment: Why do you think this is useful?

Comment: I have some really annoying development stuff that runs on virutal linux boxes on my mac.  before I can start my IDE certain process have to be up and running on the VM.  After that I can then start MY IDE.  It really sucks that I have to sit at my desktop click the same buttons and windows every day when I can set some script to start everything go get my coffee

Comment: Sounds like you just need to know when those processes are running then, a solved problem.

Comment: well I need to know those processes are all completed and no new processes will be launched.  Since they are numerically lunched on priority in theory there is a small window of opportunity for between the running of one priority and another where there is no /etc/init.d processes to be running but the system is not fully up.

Comment: I had a thought.  what does "ps aux | grep initd"  show when changing from one run level to another.  when initd has completed the run level change it is showing "initd [RUNLEVEL]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put a script in the run-level you are interested in that is the last thing to run and first thing to shut down that touches a file somewhere to indicate it has run.

For instance, if you made a script called `S99finished` and put it in the run-level folder it would run last at that run-level. A corresponding `K00finished` would run first when shutting down.

`S99finished` could look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch ~/.init_finished
```

and `K00finished` could look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e ~/.init_finished ]; then
   rm ~/.init_finished
fi
```

Then your startup script would poll until `~/.init_finished` existed at which point it would go on it's merry way.

Note, the startup scripts run as root, so using the home directory tilde will put it in root's home. That's probably not ideal for what you're doing, but illustrates the point. It's just as easy to put it in `/var/log` or somewhere else common to poll from. Just remember it has to have read permissions for everybody wherever you stick it.

Comment: I think you mean K00finished.

Comment: You're correct, silly typo's. Thanks.